# Работа с чужим приложением

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Котаны, подскажите, возможно ли проверить, установлено или нет определенное Апп (чужое) на смартфоне? И если да - его запустить?

Точнее нужно знать, установлено ли приложение TeamViewer QS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно знать схему этого приложения и просто открыть как URL. http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes